# free groups and bouquet of circles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

For any free group $F$ generated by the set $S$, one can construct a graph specifically a bouquet of circles $X$ s.t $\pi_1(X)=F$. My question is: Does this mean free groups are isomorphic to a free product of $\mathbb {Z}$? for instance, the free group generated by the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ is isomrphic to $\mathbb {Z}*\mathbb {Z}*\mathbb {Z}*\mathbb {Z}$. If not then I need some explanation to understand this! thanks in advance

Comment: Simply put, yes! (See for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product#Presentation particularly the last formula of the section *Presentation*).

Comment: this is useful .. thank u :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is to use universal properties. For free product:

> Let $H$ and $K$ be two groups. There exists a unique tripe $(G,i,j)$ with $G$ a group and $i: H \to G$, $j : K \to G$ two monomorphisms satisfying: For any group $G'$ and any morphisms $\varphi_1 : H \to G'$ and $\varphi_2 : K \to G'$, there exists a morphism $\phi : G \to G'$ such that $\varphi_1= \phi \circ i$ and $\varphi_2= \phi \circ j$.

For free group:

> Let $S$ be a set. There exists a unique group $F(S)$ such that for any group $H$, any function $f : S \to H$ extends to a morphism $\tilde{f} : F(S) \to H$.

Thus, you can show that the free group $\mathbb{F}_n$ of rank $n$ is isomorphic to the free product $\mathbb{Z} \ast \dots \ast \mathbb{Z}$ of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Since any free groups is isomorphic to a free product of some copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then how one can express the free group generated by uncountable set as a free a product of ?

Comment: The universal property can be easily generalized for free products of uncountably many groups. Therefore, if $\kappa$ is any cardinal, a free group of rank $\kappa$ is isomorphic to the free product of $\kappa$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

``Does this mean free groups are isomorphic to a free product of $\mathbb{Z}$?''

Yes, it does. See P.Hilton, S.Wylie, Homology Theory, Corollary 6.4.5.

Comment: very nice that u put the reference ,, thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Since any free groups is isomorphic to a free product of some copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then how one can express the free group generated by uncountable set as a free a product of ?

Comment: In the same manner: $F={\mathbb Z}*{\mathbb Z}*\ldots$